# gerrit : How can I squash my last 'merge commit' into one

Tags: git, gerrit

I'm new on gerrit.

I did following steps.

1. I'm using branch, named 'TeamBranch'
2. git merge master (and fix conflicts)
3. git commit
4. git push to gerrit

while reviewing my merge patch, someone pushed a patch to 'TeamBranch' branch.

so I did
4. git pull

1. git rebase -i HEAD~2

but the commit log doesn't show only one 'merge commit' but every commit from master's..

How can I do rebase simply?

Comment: You did both a pull and a rebase? The pull actually does a merge, which should fix your merge conflict in Gerrit (provided you are allowed to push merge commits to Gerrit).

Comment: Regarding your question "How can I squash my last 'merge commit' into one", when you rebase, all your merge commits should be omitted, so no squashing of merge commits needed.